# how to create simple and advance tool tip for canvas points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hey I am trying to create a tooltip over canvas points. I have a very simple triangle and I want to create a tool-tip over each edge of his points. It means I need 3 tooltips for 3 points of the triangle.
This is what I have achieve so far, I have succeeded in adding listeners to mosueover and mosueclick.
Can I add a tooltip to each point, if so can I add such tooltip to a circle?

**Update:**

I have go over the following link: [tooltip canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606816/jquery-tooltip-in-base-of-canvas-coordinates) and implement it on my code.
The problem is that , the tool tip doesn't show over each point in the triangle and it has glitches.
I have update the code,please have a look over it.
this is the new addition:

```
if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
  $tip.text("I have a tip for you:(x:" + mouse.x + "y:" + mouse.y + ")");
  $tip.css({
    left: e.clientX + 3,
    top: e.clientY - 18
  }).show();
```

The problem is that the tooltip appear far away from the current position when I click inside the triangle.

```js
$(function() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var triangle = [{
    x: 58,
    y: 845
  }, {
    x: 984,
    y: 845
  }, {
    x: 521,
    y: 41
  }];
  drawTriangle(triangle);
  $tip = $('#tip');
  $tip.hide();

  // define tooltips for each data point  
  function drawTriangle(t) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(t[0].x, t[0].y);
    ctx.lineTo(t[1].x, t[1].y);
    ctx.lineTo(t[2].x, t[2].y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.stroke();
  }
  var canvasPosition = {
    x: canvas.offsetLeft,
    y: canvas.offsetTop
  };

  canvas.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // use pageX and pageY to get the mouse position
    // relative to the browser window
    var mouse = {
      x: e.pageX - canvasPosition.x,
      y: e.pageY - canvasPosition.y
    }
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(mouse.x, mouse.y)) {
      $tip.text("I have a tip for you:(x:" + mouse.x + "y:" + mouse.y + ")");
      $tip.css({
        left: e.clientX + 3,
        top: e.clientY - 18
      }).show();
    }

  });

})
```

```css
#tip {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas-wrapper">
  <canvas id="canvas" width=1024 height=980></canvas>
  <div id=tip>Tooltip</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606816/jquery-tooltip-in-base-of-canvas-coordinates

Comment: please see update post, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your updated code almost works, but you need to account for window scrolling.

You can do that by subscribing to the `window.onscroll` event and then updating the canvas offset variables. Resizing the window will also affect the canvas's relative position so update the canvas offset variables in response to the `window.onresize` event also.

```
// create vars that hold the canvas offset vs the window
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();

// subscribe to scroll & resize events
// and recalculate the offset 
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

// calculate the current canvas offset vs the window
function reOffset(){
    var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    offsetX=BB.left;
    offsetY=BB.top;        
}
```

Comment: Hey I have a problem, I get always  offsetX and offsetY equal zero when I scroll. this is what the debug output.